# Yolov7 docker image size exceeding 6GB /issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, yolo, amazon-ecr, yolov8

I am building a docker image which I want to store on ECR(AWS) . My expections with the yolomodel is to just take an image as an input and get predicted set of pose-keypoints as output using YOLOv7-pose.

Following are in `requirements.txt` in docker :

```
boto3==1.20.23
boto3-stubs == 1.21.0
aws_lambda_typing==2.9.2
requests==2.25.1
protobuf==4.25.3
pytz == 2023.3
torch == 2.0.1
opencv-python == 4.9.0.80
dateTime == 5.4
pybase64 ==1.3.2
ultralytics ==8.1.0
typing-extensions == 3.7.4.3
```

and this is how I am importing it in `application.py`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import boto3
import base64
import json
import torch
import math 
import pytz
from ultralytics import YOLO
from datetime import datetime
```

Earlier I used mediapipe to do same which led me to docker size of only 500MB.

Answer (score 0):

The image is being inflated by the Python packages:

```
234076  ./nvidia/cusparse/lib
234416  ./nvidia/cusparse
235296  ./nvidia/nccl/lib
235344  ./nvidia/nccl
274220  ./nvidia/cufft/lib
274300  ./nvidia/cufft
368104  ./nvidia/cusolver/lib
368384  ./nvidia/cusolver
473492  ./nvidia/cublas/lib
473908  ./nvidia/cublas
880240  ./nvidia/cudnn/lib
880696  ./nvidia/cudnn
1252564 ./torch/lib
1359700 ./torch
2647496 ./nvidia
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8.0-slim

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

The size of the image is 7.7 GB and the `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` directory alone is 4.8 GB.

I'm checking the image size with:

```
docker inspect  -f "{{ .Size }}" <image-name> | numfmt --to=si
```

Using `--no-cache-dir` will reduce the size of the image.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8.0-slim

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

The size of the image is now 5.3 GB.

However, when I tried to load the packages using the code from the original question I had a problem with a missing dependency.

So I went back to first principles and simplified `requirements.txt`:

```
boto3==1.34.55
ultralytics==8.1.0
```

With those dependencies the image builds and packages load.

[image]

Since we are not specifying particular versions for all of the other packages, they are simply selected to be compatible with `boto3` and `ultralytics`, which seems to result in consistently larger footprints. For example, we get version 2.2.1 of `torch`.

```
94432   ./nvidia/curand/lib
96536   ./nvidia/curand
189712  ./nvidia/cusolver/lib
189796  ./nvidia/cufft/lib
189876  ./nvidia/cufft
189992  ./nvidia/cusolver
214328  ./nvidia/nccl/lib
214392  ./nvidia/nccl
258688  ./nvidia/cusparse/lib
259000  ./nvidia/cusparse
347436  ./triton/_C
428852  ./triton
608716  ./nvidia/cublas/lib
609300  ./nvidia/cublas
1155416 ./nvidia/cudnn/lib
1155880 ./nvidia/cudnn
1442728 ./torch/lib
1556592 ./torch
2877384 ./nvidia
```

You can probably fiddle around with specific versions of those packages but it seems unlikely that you will get the image down to 500 MB.

Sorry, I know that this is not really an "answer". But maybe there is something useful.

Comment: Thanks for going through my question and understanding my issue. 
From your answer, I could confirm that ultralytics itself is causing size to explode because of its dependecies whereas mediapipe isn't. Probably I should find better package or better model which does not cause such thing.

Comment: Yes! It's `ultralytics` and dependencies which are inflating the image. I guess it depends. Does this image need to be small? Can you get away with a larger image? Because finding something that does the same job as `ultralytics` and updating your client code accordingly will take time. Perhaps just settle for a larger image?